# Google Spreadsheet Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a trigger that activates on weekdays only and at a specific time, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
function createTriggers() {
    var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
                ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,
                ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];

    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();

    if (time == '3:05:00 PM EDT') {
        for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            ScriptApp.newTrigger(Lunch1)
            .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
            .everyMinutes().create();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to do. When does createTriggers will be executed?

Comment: In my script I use the If statement to make the triger look at each MIN and only activate when it reaches 3:05 PM.

Comment: Im trying to activate a function, with a trigger at a specific time every week day.

Comment: I got that but what you're doing is creating the triggers at a specific time and not actually triggering them at this time

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm really new to writing scrip. Only been doing it for a few days now. I didn't realized I wasn't triggering them.

Comment: See I thought the .create(); was what triggered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you mean you want to make it so a function is triggered (runs) every weekday at a certain time of the day. Here's what I would do.

First, in the Script Editor:

1. Go to Resources - Current Project's Triggers
2. Click Add a new trigger
3. Select the function that you want to be triggered
4. Change the next box to "Time-driven"
5. Change the next box to "Hour timer"
6. Then change the last box to "every hour"

Then at the very beginning of your function, add this code:

```
var d = new Date(); 
if (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0) return;
// more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp
```

That will stop the rest of the script from running if it's a Saturday or Sunday.

Then, say you want the script to only run at one specific time each weekday, you could set the time-driven trigger to "Every minute" and then add another if statement after the one above:

```
if (d.getHours() != 15 && d.getMinutes() != 5) return;
```

That will stop the rest of the script from running if it's not exactly 15:05 (3:05 PM).

This is definitely not the most efficient way to do this, but it works.

Also, this is worth mentioning: I'm not sure if there's anything that would prevent you from triggering the script every minute. Google does impose quotas for what your scripts can do, but I didn't see anything about how many times a script can be triggered in a day. Here's the chart: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Allow yourself a little latitude when specifying times so precisely. There is rarely time drift between Google servers but it does happen. Specifying a minute like that might be better as a ramge of +/-5

Comment: OP, this is a good suggestion. How precise do you need the time to be?

Comment: I only need it on the half hour once a day. Like at 2:30 once a day. So if I do put it at triggering every 30 mins will it check for example 1:00, 1:30,2:00,230....and so on? Or it start checking every 30 mins from the time I save the script? Also I tried testing the script you suggested above with a min interval for the trigger time and it seems to be ignoring the if statement and triggering the function regardless of it being the time I set it for or not.

Comment: Add this line right after the variable declaration line for d: Logger.log("Hours: %s, Minutes: %s",d.getHours(),d.getMinutes());

Comment: Then run the script and after it finishes, go to View - Logs and see those values. Then you can use that to refine your if statements. I think when setting the interval to 30 minutes, the Google servers just pick a random time and run it every 30 minutes. So maybe you'd want to stop the script if the current time is not within a 45-minute window.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
function createTriggers(func, hour) {
  var weekdays = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];

  for (var dayIndex in weekdays) {
    var day = weekdays[dayIndex];

    ScriptApp.newTrigger(func).timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(day).atHour(hour).create();
  }
}
```

This code creates a trigger for weekdays in a specific time calling the `func` function.

Comment: But I want to be able to do it at the half hour as well. That's why I thought you had to use the .everyMinutes and check each min with an If statement.

Comment: You want to execute a function every minute for half an hour?